# extraer del campo nombre los doctores sin traer repetidos

Tags: mysql

tengo una lista de paciente y tiene un campo llamado doctor donde se agrega su nombre pero esta repetido muchas veces por ejemplo

referencia = 4 (4 se refiere que son doctores)

```
SELECT referencia as nombre_doctor FROM `pacientes` WHERE `id_cat_referidos`=4

tabla pacientes

    nombre_doctor
    luis enrique
    enrique luis
    luis
    perez luis fernando
```

para estos 4 es el mismo doctor pero agregado muchas veces y quiero migrar estos nombres a una tabla de doctores

Comment: no compredo tu pregunta,  quieres un select que traiga los nombre de los doctores sin repetirse?

Comment: sii es un select pero tengo doctores con el mismo nombre y apellido primero ponen su apellido  y luego sus nombres o viceversa

Comment: ah quieres normalizar tus datos? si es asi lo veo complicado ya que un nombre lo puedes escribir de varias formas ys er la misma persona

Comment: si eso quiero hacer normalizar

Comment: creo que tendras que hacerlo de forma manual, no hay una forma de saber si Luis Peres = luis por ejemplo